# Facebook share widget creates broken WIDGET_LIKE_LOG_APP link

Tags: facebook

I created a Facebook share widget on my page. When I use the widget to share the page to my own Facebook account, I find that the box that gets created on my timeline contains a link "`WIDGET_LIKE_LOG_APP`".

When I click that link, it takes me to a page

```
https://www.facebook.com/games/?app_id=107599262613689
```

with the error message :

> Sorry, WIDGET_LIKE_LOG_APP hasn't been approved for display in App
>   Center.

How can I prevent Facebook from creating that `WIDGET_LIKE_LOG_APP` link?

Code on my page to create the share widget:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function (d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s);
        js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.3";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
    }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
<div class="fb-like" data-href="@Model.Url" data-layout="button_count" data-action="like" data-show-faces="true" data-share="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reported this issue to Facebook. They confirmed this was a bug. They've now come back to me saying the bug has been fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your code it seems you are using the [Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) instead of the [Share Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/share-button).

Anyway the problem is that you are not specifying an appId on the widget definition (on the js.src parameter). You can use the wizard on the [Like Button](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button) page to get the specific code that you should embed in your page.